# go-ethereum POA with clique - issue with add new signers when all old signers are removed

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, clique

I have setup a POA network with Clique consensus on azure. Due to some issue all the signer vms got deleted and we have no more signers and only normal geth nodes.

So i tried updating the geth nodes to signers. clique propose doesnt seem to work anyway i try.

Is there any procedure I have to follow in this kind of situation ?

I have 3 nodes which are all geth nodes. And connected. I want to make all 3 of them signers.

Thank you.

Comment: How can you propose new signer when you have no existing singers?